# how to convert String time to dateTime format in php?

Tags: php, datetime

I want to check who is greater datetime between two datetime variables.

I have an string of datetime and i want to convert it into datetime format and check it who is greater?

my variables:

```
$d1 = '2016-02-02 07:35:00';
$d2 = '2016-02-1 13:10:31';
```

and I want to check who is greater between above two variables.

```
if($d1>$d2)
{
return true;
}
```

Comment: You can use strtotime to compare them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are comparison operators for the DateTime class in php . Something like this :

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

$d1 = new DateTime('2008-08-03 14:52:10');
$d2 = new DateTime('2008-01-03 11:11:10');
var_dump($d1 == $d2);
var_dump($d1 > $d2);
var_dump($d1 < $d2);
```

**Output**

```
bool(false)
bool(true)
bool(false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `strtotime()`

```
$d1 = strtotime('2016-02-02 07:35:00');
$d2 = strtotime('2016-02-1 13:10:31');

if($d1>$d2){
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)

```
if (new DateTime($d1) > new DateTime($d2) {
   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `strtotime()` function like this :

```
if(strtotime($d1) > strtotime($d2))
{
return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$d1 = strtotime('2016-02-02 07:35:00');
$d2 = strtotime('2016-02-1 13:10:31');

if($d1 > $d2)
{
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compare like that:

```
<?
$d1 = '2016-02-02 07:35:00';
$d2 = '2016-02-1 13:10:31';

$ts1 = strtotime($d1); // 1454394900
$ts2 = strtotime($d2); // 1454328631

if($ts1>$ts2) // 1454394900 > 1454328631 = true
{
    echo 1; // return this.
}
else{
    echo 0;
}

?>
```

Use `strtotime()` for both date and than compare.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$date = '1994-04-27 11:35:00';
$date1 = '2016-02-10 13:10:31';

$stt = strtotime($date); // 767439300

$stt1 = strtotime($date1); // 1455106231


if($stt>$stt1) 

    echo 1; 

else
    echo 0;


?>
```

use strtotime function to convert string to time formate...